# Plot a surface with lists of latitude, longitude and elevation data (hillshading)

Tags: python, google-maps, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I found this script on the matplotlib website:

```
"""
Demonstrates using custom hillshading in a 3D surface plot.
"""
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cbook
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import LightSource
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

filename = cbook.get_sample_data('jacksboro_fault_dem.npz', asfileobj=False)
with np.load(filename) as dem:
    z = dem['elevation']
    nrows, ncols = z.shape
    x = np.linspace(dem['xmin'], dem['xmax'], ncols)
    y = np.linspace(dem['ymin'], dem['ymax'], nrows)
    x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

region = np.s_[5:50, 5:50]
x, y, z = x[region], y[region], z[region]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))

ls = LightSource(270, 45)
# To use a custom hillshading mode, override the built-in shading and pass
# in the rgb colors of the shaded surface calculated from "shade".
rgb = ls.shade(z, cmap=cm.gist_earth, vert_exag=0.1, blend_mode='soft')
surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=rgb,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False, shade=False)

plt.show()
```

They use the file `jacksboro_fault_dem.npz` to plot the elevation data and they get something like that:

[image: 3D Plot]

Thanks to Google Earth I was able to get the text file `maido_elevation_data.txt` with latitude, longitude and elevation data of the following area (Maïdo, Reunion Island):

[image: Maïdo, Reunion Island]

I made a function to get 3 lists for each coordinate from the text file:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_LAT_LONG_ALT(text_file):
    ch=""
    LAT=[]
    LONG=[]
    ALT=[]
    with open(text_file,"r") as fich:
        for ligne in fich:
            for e in ligne:
                ch+=e
            liste=ch.replace("\n","").split("\t")
            LAT.append(float(liste[0]))
            LONG.append(float(liste[1]))
            ALT.append(float(liste[2]))
            ch=""
    return LAT,LONG,ALT

fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")

X = get_LAT_LONG_ALT("maido_elevation_data.txt")[0]
Y = get_LAT_LONG_ALT("maido_elevation_data.txt")[1]
Z = get_LAT_LONG_ALT("maido_elevation_data.txt")[2]

axes.scatter(X,Y,Z, c="r", marker="o")

axes.set_xlabel("Latitude")
axes.set_ylabel("Longitude")
axes.set_zlabel("Altitude")

plt.show()
```

How should I modify the script to get a good surface plot with my own data like they do?

PS: I will give you the links of the files in the comments because I'm not allowed to put more than 2 links... yes, I'm new :)

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/custom_shaded_3d_surface.html
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7P95aWmH4DUelhIdHJjUG5RMmc/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7P95aWmH4DUVzJhbmhoSENLTzg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reshape your data it is a three column data x,y and z
You should have a file with only z values in a 2D table columns are x and rows are y.
Meshgrid fucntion in python should help.